# If an inner loop is incremented by squaring the variable, what will be the runtime of it and how?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime

Say if n here is any number less than 256
the inner loop is going to be true for 4 times,
now what kind of sequence does the inner loop follow as n increases.

```
for ( int i=1; i<=n; i++){
    for ( int j=2;j<=n; j=j*j){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outer loop will be iterated `n` times. The inner loop each time squared the previous value, i.e., `2 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^8 + ... + 2^{2^k}`. Hence, the time complexity is `n * k`. To compute the `k`, we need to find a `k` such that `n  = 2 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^8 + ... + 2^{2^k}`:

```
2 + 2^2 + 2^4 + 2^8 + ... + 2^{2^k} = sum_{t=0}^{k} 2^{2^t} = n 
=>  k = \theta(log(log(n))
```

Therefore, the time complexity if `Theta(n log(log(n)))`.